# Why does the login screen in 14.04 only change when I set a picture background, but not when I use a solid color?

Tags: login, desktop-background

When I set a solid color as desktop background (like black), which I like far better, then the login screen shows the default purplish picture (warty-final-ubuntu.png). How to I make it also show a simple black screen?

Btw, I educated myself about lightdm settings and access rights to pictures in /usr/share/backgrounds, so I specifically ask for an answer that does not involve any picture files, since I want a simple, single color, no gradient.

In response to first comment, I think I still need more specific knowledge about lightdm.

First of all, im using Ubuntu 14.04 and the configuration files I am looking at are in this directory:

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
```

Is it supposed to work in a way that all these files are always read, when lightdm starts (maybe in lexical order)?
Is there something else I would have to look at?
I specifically tried setting this:

```
background='#000000'
```

but it had no effect whatsoever (still showing warty-final-ubuntu.png), that's why I came here.

Edit:
@kenn Actually, in my case that file does not exist.

```
thomas@thomas-laptop:~$ ls /etc/lightdm/
users.conf
```

Comment: have you tried setting the background in dconf-tools to a file that does not exist so that there would be nothing displayed ( black )?

Comment: Easiest option might be to create a black image yourself and use that(?)

Comment: which greeter do you use? output of `cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf | grep  ^greeter-session=`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I know of to change the background on the lightdm login screen is to use Ubuntu-Tweak. If you don't have it, install it from the software-center, or the terminal, by typing

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Open Ubuntu-Tweak and go to Tweaks>Login Settings. Click 'unlock' at the top of the window and enter your password, then click the icon for changing the login screen background. Select the picture you want and click 'open'. Of course, this selects an image from /usr/share/backgrounds.

Go to the internet and find a black image and save it to /usr/share/backgrounds. Select that image from Ubuntu-Tweak. 
Saving to /usr/share/backgrounds will require you to save the image somewhere else first, and then copy it to there. Open the Terminal or press Alt+F2, and type

`gksudo nautilus`

and enter your password. This will open nautilus as root and allow you to navigate and copy to /usr/share/backgrounds.

Hope this is helpful.